# FirebaseAuth - Compat problems (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUV())

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication, nosuchmethoderror

I have an android project that keeps crashing on startup since I added:
firebase auth.

What I've done :

1. Added the google-services.json to the app level folder
2. Added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in build.gradle (top level)
3. And here is my build.gradle content (app level)

here it goes:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the stacktrace when it crashes:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: xxx.xxxx, PID: 8425

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUV()Ljava/lang/String; in 
class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 
'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/xxx.xxx-2/base.apk)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at xxx.xxxx.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:82)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Is the crash happening in the emulator or on device? Pretty sure the emulator comes with its own version of Play and you need to use the one that matches up with your Firebase Auth version.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Proguard requires some special config. See "Optional: Configure ProGuard" in [this setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that my google play service sdk was not installed in android studio. After installing it, I cleaned the project and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add the firebase core library`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Try by using lower version of auth like

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
```

or something like `9.9.0` etc

Comment: Have you enabled the OAuth providers service in Firebase Authentication Section ?

Comment: I found the problem lol, its my fault, I had not installed google play services sdk on my new pc. After the install, i "cleaned project" and everything was good.

Comment: hehehe..any way ..we are get addicted of stackoverflow too! :p